# Why is my cookie not loading data from a textarea?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get values from a textarea element and put them into a cookie like so:

```
function makeCookie(){
    var body = document.getElementById("input").value;
    document.cookie = "input="+body;
    console.log("Cookie: "+document.cookie);
}
```

While I would expect that console.log would show the extracted values in the cookie, it instead spits this out:

```
Cookie: input={
```

Also, my html code for the textarea looks like this:

```
<textarea name="input" id="input" spellcheck="false">
    "{
        "data":123
    }"
</textarea>
```

How would I get this to work?

Comment: To make sure that you have all the information for us to hep out, please post the relevant HTML code, such as how you are creating the `textarea`. I know it seems silly, but it might help, especially with spelling mistakes. Also, take the Tour to make sure you are asking Questions correctly. You can avoid down votes and unnecessary comments by following the suggestions on how to ask a question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion -- I've now got the relevant html in the question.

Comment: cookies shouldn't be multiline - they have to be encoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `encodeURIComponent` so that the multiline string can be properly stored. To read its actual value, use `decodeURIComponent`.

```
function makeCookie(body){
    document.cookie = "input="+encodeURIComponent(body);
    console.log("Cookie: "+document.cookie);
}
makeCookie(`{
        "data":123
    }`);
```